# thread pool without starvation issues - c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Let's assume we have a thread pool that is generic - with the commonly expected properties - you can assign a task and in first possibility the pool will allocate resource to resolve it.

It is a very common problem such thread pools to have starvation issues when some tasks spawn subtasks and wait for them. The problem is that the currently active tasks might exhaust the available threads and they all block each other without resource to unblock any of them.

I have implemented two strategies in the past that works semi-ok:

1. Track for starvation and create more threads to resolve it. This have obvious issue - depending on the deepness there might be a lot of extra threads needed.
2. Reuse the thread for a subtask. When subtasks are created the waiting functionality is smart to use the thread for some of the subtask if still waiting. This way there is guarantee that there will be no completely blocked task. This strategy though complicates prioritization and requires immutable data (else it might create very complicated algorithmic and locking issues).

My question is - do you know better strategy, or which of these two seems more applicable for generic use case.

Comment: Don't spawn the subtasks on the same pool?

Comment: I am not sure how this is going to work for general case where you could have thousands of levels - it will require thousands of thread-pools. How this is better than extra threads to handle the blocking tasks?

Comment: Usually a simple functional separation goes a long way: E.g. have incoming connections handled by one thread pool, and outgoing ones by a different one. Otherwise you'd not only suffer starvation, but potentially outright deadlocks.

Comment: why is any task waiting for a potentially unbounded tree of spawned subtasks to finish? Instead, the rest of the task could be another task, to be scheduled/activated when the subtasks finish. The original task can simply end after spawning the subtasks.

Comment: @arayq2 Event driven is an option. It tends to complicate implementation of even simple algorithms though.

Comment: @KerrekSB this is not webservice related question. In general case the tasks are not limited to two groups.